Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path:
Hello can anyone help me to fix this problem Please
pip install rasterio pandas numpy tensorfl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Could+not+install+packages+due+to+an+OSError%3A+Could+not+find+a+suitable+TLS+CA+certificate+bundle%2C+invalid+path
